# Using threads to calculate values in the background

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, backgroundworker

I am working on a program that queries information from a remote computer. WMI, registry, etc. I have most of that all finished up, but without threading it runs pretty slow. (I assume it is waiting for a response from the the remote machine for every single request before moving on to the next one).

I've read up on different methods of threading. Thread class, BackgroundWorker class, Task class. I can thread all the queries without any problems, but getting all the information back to the main thread so it can format and display the information in RichTextBoxs on the main XAML window. I keep getting errors that I can't access variables because they are being used by other threads, etc.

Can anyone give me some insight on how to manage/return variables calculated/retrieved by other threads? I've watched numerous videos and read several articles on threading, but I can't find any that really explain how threading actually works, and how I'm supposed to know when I can and can't access a variable from a different thread, etc.

Comment: The easy entry into GUI+threading is the Backgroundworker. Make sure to use only the Completed event to update the GUI.

Comment: I'm not sure about your specific implementation so if you could provide some code I might be able to help you further but in the meantime this tutorial is a good start: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threads are a low level abstraction from the hardware whereas Tasks provide similar asynchronous work but also allow for return results, exception management, etc. By default in Windows UIs, you cannot modify a UI element unless you are on the thread that created it. The BackgroundWorker class is an older helper class that helped you marshal the results back onto the UI thread.

Tasks provide a much more straightforward way to deal with this now. Execute you worker code in a Task and then put the code that updates the UI in the continuation of the task. The trick is to tell the continuation to run on the original UI thread, i.e. the UI's synchronization context. Otherwise it will default to the prior Task's context (which would be the thread pool by default)

Here is an example that executes the DoWork() method as a Task and then updates an TextBlock on the UI with the result of the Task. Since the Button_Click is invoked from the UI, its context is the UI thread. We just pass that context to the ContinueWith() method to execute the continuation code on that context.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var t = Task.Run(() => DoWork());

    t.ContinueWith(
        // take the result of the Task and update the UI
        completedTask => Output.Text = completedTask.Result.ToString()
        // tell the Task Continuation to run on the original UI context
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
        );
}

private int DoWork()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard windows UI problem (WinForms, XAML) - the data is coming from another thread than the UI thread. You can read about how to avoid the problem [WinForms - in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx) and [WPF XAML in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx). The (not so new anymore) Task Parallel Library in .NET 4.x offers a really good and easy synchronization context. You can read how to use it here: [Task Synchronisation Context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/18/parallel-programming-task-schedulers-and-synchronization-context.aspx).

There is also the new [**async/await**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx) concept, but i haven't used it yet, so i can't say anything about it.

Threading and Task(ing) are two different things in the background, but IMHO Tasks are sufficient for trivial asynchronous operations. I find the library very easy to use, mainly because of the fluent API and the synchronization context support. More about the [Task Parallel Library can be found here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)

Comment: The question talks about XAML, so I don't think it's about Winforms. Though the threading issues are basically identical in WPF too.

Comment: This is a general windows UI _problem_, independent of the UI concept - the solution is the same for both WinForms and WPF(XAML). The TPL can be used in the exact same way in a WPF application. I admit there are WPF specific solutions too, that i have not listed, but in general everything is the same. I edited my answer.